# flutter native splash screen does not working in the dark mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i have this code in my pupspec.yaml file

```
flutter_native_splash :
  image : assets\s.png
  color : "#FCE4EC"
  image_dark : assets\d.png
  color_dark : "#2a2f49"
```

but when i run the app even if it's in the dark mode it gives me the light mode image and color .

i have this code in my main function for specifing the theme :

```
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isDark = prefs!.getBool('isDark') == null?false : prefs!.getBool('isDark')!;
```

and i have this line in my MaterialApp class :

```
themeMode: isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
```

i tried to change the themeMode from :

```
themeMode: isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
```

to :

```
themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
```

and it worked properly , but i want it to work using the isDark boolean .

any ideas how can i solve this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76396591/flutter-native-splash-not-working-and-show-only-white-dark-screen/76399490#76399490

Comment: i tried your solution, the same error @rasityilmaz

Comment: There are parameters in the native_splash.yaml file in the answer I sent, you can try them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76399490/15812214

Comment: Can you specify the parameters you're talking about @rasityilmaz

Comment: Search in file ' # Platform specific images can be specified with the following parameters, which will override
  # the respective parameter.  You may specify all, selected, or none of these parameters:'

Comment: did not solve the problem ,to be more specify the flutter native splash theme is matching the system theme not the app theme ,any ideas how can i solve this ?
thanks for your help .

Comment: https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/17